# Delimitate Multi Lined Cells in Excel or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, delimited

***Old Prompt***

I've been trying to find a method of delimitating cells in Excel using the new line in the text with no luck. I need to delimitate a Cells string into multiple columns separated by the New Lines in the string so now I'm trying to find a way to do this with Visual Basics App. Does anyone have any useful advice or recommendations?

***New Prompt***

In the earlier portion of this assignment the goal was:

- recognize *Chr(10)*
- delimitate the text downward into a new column
- keep the data from the same row

Previously I did not know there was a character that represented the new line. This is to say that I've found the solution to my problem and shared my results below.

Comment: For example  - https://www.encodedna.com/excel/split-text-with-carriage-returns-to-multiple-columns-using-vba-macro.htm

Comment: `Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Range("B1"), xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=vbLf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***OP ANSWER***

It's me again. I know this might seem a bit messy and maybe not as efficient as it could be, but this is essentially what I was looking for. I hope this helps anyone in the future. Feel free to message me with any questions or concerns.

***CODE***

```
Sub Test()
    Dim CountRows, FirstPortion, FullString, Row, Col
    
    'Manually Set This Value
    Row = 2
    Col = 4
    CountRows = 8
'    '~~maybe i should count number of rows and increase count each time that a row is delimitated
'    '~~~or just the same increase count when a new row is inserted
'    '~~this would avoid the process of rechecking that a row has more to be delimitated
    '------------------------------***{ROW TRAVERSAL}***---------------------------------
    Do While Row < CountRows + 1
        
        '---------------------------***{INITIALIZE}***-----------------------------------
        FullString = Cells(Row, Col)
        Debug.Print "Row"; Row; ":"; "FullString:"
        Debug.Print FullString
        
        
        '--------------------------***{REPLACEMENT}***----------------------------------
        'If the row we point to contains a new line char then we want to replace newlines with "."
        If InStr(FullString, Chr(10)) > 0 Then
            
            Debug.Print "Row"; Row; " Info:"; " There is more than one line"
'            'replaces new line char with periods
            FullString = Trim(Replace(FullString, Chr(10), "."))
            Debug.Print "Row"; Row; ":"; "FullString:"
            Debug.Print FullString
            
'            'counts number of periods in the current row
'            '****{might not need}****
'            Count = Len(Cells(Row, Col)) - Len(Replace(Cells(Row, 4), ".", ""))

        End If
        
        
        '---------------------------***{EXTRACTION}***----------------------------------
        '------------------------------***{LOOP}***----------------------------------
        'If the Row we point to contains a "." then that implies there is more names to be delimitated
        'Knowing this we want to isolate the first portion of the String and isolate the remaining portion
        'the remaining portion should be moved to the next inserted row
        If InStr(FullString, ".") > 0 Then
        
            Debug.Print "Row"; Row; " Info:"; " There is more than one period"
            FirstPortion = Left(FullString, InStr(FullString, ".") - 1)
            Debug.Print "Row"; Row; ":"; "FirstPortion:"
            Debug.Print FirstPortion
            FullString = Right(FullString, (Len(FullString) - Len(FirstPortion) - 1))
            Debug.Print "Row"; Row; ":"; "FullString:"
            Debug.Print FullString
            
            '-----------------------***{INSERTION}***----------------------------------
            'Now that the strings are seperated we must insert a new row to move the information to
            Rows(Row + 1).Insert
            CountRows = CountRows + 1
            Debug.Print "Update the Row Count:"; CountRows
            
            '-----------------------***{COPY DATA}***-----------------------------------
            'Copy the relative data into the new row
            Rows(Row).Copy Rows(Row + 1)
            
            '-------------------***{DELIMITATE NAMES}***--------------------------------
            'Set Current Row to first name to be delimitated
            Cells(Row, Col) = FirstPortion
            'Set Next Row to remaining names
            Cells(Row + 1, Col) = FullString
            
        End If
        
        Row = Row + 1
        Debug.Print "Row Pointing to:"; Row
        
    Loop
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

***DUMMY DATA***

[image]

***RESULT***

[image]